# pandas: column name with ' separator

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Im reading a file which has a column with a `'` in the column. Something like

df:

```
colA  col'21 colC 
abc   2001   Ab1
```

now I can't seem to read the column like:

```
df['col\'21']
```

It gives the KeyError.

Comment: `df["col'21"]` ?

Comment: nope, that does not work either

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.info()` and how do you read your file?

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: KeyError: "col'21"

Comment: `['colA', 'col’21', 'colC']`

Comment: So use `df["Col’21"]`

Comment: `’` is not the same character as `'`

Answer (score 1):

Your character is not a quote but the [Right Single Quotation Mark](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8217)

Replace this character by the standard quote:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\u2019', "'")
print(df["col'21"])
```

To find the unicode character, use:

```
>>> hex(ord("’"))
'0x2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `’` instead:

instead of:

```
df[YTD'21"]
```

try:

```
df["YTD’21"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col'21":[1,2,3]})
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"""col'21""":[1,2,3]})
```

Output:

```
   col'21
0       1
1       2
2       3
```